# whene i add javafx to eclipse from "install new software"

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I'm wanna install new software in eclipse luna version, but it has error during the installation! The error is:
The operation cannot be completed.  See the details.

Comment: Your software is compatible with your JDK and with your Eclipse version ?

Comment: Well look at the details - and tell us what they say.